# Hiding navbar on front-page with jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, navbar

I'm trying to hide the navbar on a Wordpress **front-page only**, and only until the user scrolls a certain amount of pixels, after which the navbar re-appears. All other pages should have a normal, always visible navbar.

I have this code in header.php:

```
 <head>
 <script>

 (function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
          $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "#3d3938");
        } else {
          $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    });
  });
 }(jQuery));

 </script>
 </head>
```

On its own, the above code **works** exactly as intended for hiding the navbar, but since the navbar is in header.php, it hides it on all pages.

So I add an if condition that checks if we're on front-page:

```
<head>
<script>  

if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){

// Front-page
alert('Hello');

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
          $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "#3d3938");
        } else {
          $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    });
  });

} else {

// Other pages
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
}

 </script>
 </head>
```

the condition works, as the alert() is shown only on front-page, but the hide/scroll effect no longer works. I'm guessing I am not properly inserting the code into the if condition, I've tried like a million combinations but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't reference `JQuery` as `$`.

Do the following:

```
<head>
<script>  
(function ($) {
    if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){

        // Front-page
        alert('Hello');

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                    $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "#3d3938");
                } else {
                    $('.navbar-bg').css("background-color", "transparent");
                }
            });
        });

    } else {

        // Other pages
        console.log(window.location.pathname);
    }
}(jQuery));
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!